# Parse String to double from EditText causes runtime error

Tags: java, string, parsing, android-edittext, runtime-error

first things first i´m totally new to coding and especially android dev :-) Right now I´m trying to make a small budgeting app for myself.

The idea is to take in a user input through a EditText and then hit a plus or minus button to subtract or add the given number from a balance. The problem is my app crashes after hitting the minus button. My code is the following.

// 1. Takes the AMOUNT given by the User and subtracts it from the total balance

// 2. Prints out the new Balance

```
protected void decrement(View view) {
    EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    double minus = Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());
    balance -= minus;
    displayBalance();
}
```

// Prints out the balance to the screen

```
private void displayBalance() {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance_TextView);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + balance);
}
```

Through the Debugger & commenting out lines I´m pretty sure, that the error comes from the following line:

`double minus = Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());`

(suprise suprise xD)

This is the runtime error from the log: (sorry for the mess & thx for your help)

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.example.android.moneymama, PID: 2618
>                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                                    at 
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10,00"
>                                                                                    at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>                                                                                    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.example.android.moneymama.MainActivity.decrement(MainActivity.java:32)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10,00" at`

The string from the edit text contains a comma, which the method does not understand. So in-case you want to enter a decimal, then enter `10.0` or if you want a number in the thousands then simply enter it without a comma: `10000`

Comment: No worries it happens, glad I helped.